# C++ Providing arbitrary parameter for a templated array to check against?

Tags: c++, templates

Lets say I have a struct

```
struct FStruct
{
    FName ObjectName;
};
```

And I have a templated static function

```
template <typename T, typename LookType>
static T* GetFromArray(LookType LookFor, TArray<T> InArray)
{
    for (T* TIter : InArray)
    {
        if (LookFor == TIter.LookParameter)  // <-- How to provide LookParameter?
        {
            return TIter;
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

I need to provide it a variable from that ObjClass to check against, how do I do that?

Essentially the usage could be something like:

```
MyStaticLib::GetFromArray<FStruct, FName>(FName("Bob"), PeopleArray, FStruct::ObjectName)
```

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly work, at all. If `Titer` is a `T *`, then I do not see how `Titer.somethingorother` would be valid C++.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the standard [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) function. First of all, don't try to reinvent the wheel, but if you do then look how one overload handles all possible iterable types comparison using a *predicate* (something that is callable, like a pointer to a function, or a an object with a `operator()` member function (which includes [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda))).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Was worried that might be the case, is there an alternative way to essentially do the above? Supposing not.. I could have overloaded functions as a last resort for different parameter types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not really possible to pass the name of a field in the manner you are suggesting, this smacks of reflection which C++ does not have. What you can do quite easily in modern C++ though is pass a function which encodes the name of the field as part of its logic. This ends up boiling down to the suggestion of Joachim Pileborg in the comments. Namely, you can write:

```
auto found = std::find_if(InArray.begin(), InArray.end(), 
    [&] (const auto& x) {
        return x.LookParameter == LookFor;
});
```

You can wrap this in a function or a function template, but all that will really buy you is not having to call begin and end. There's no clean way to make it so that the user doesn't have to pass the lambda, which includes the `==`, but honestly this isn't so bad.

There is a not clean way, which is to write a macro:

```
#define GET_FROM_ARRAY(array, fieldname, lookfor) \
    std::find_if( array .begin(), array .end(), \
    [&] (const auto& x) { \
        return x. fieldname == lookfor ; \
    })

auto found = GET_FROM_ARRAY(InArray, FName, LookFor);
```

As a C++ programmer, I'm simultaneously obligated to provide this answer as it's technically speaking the closest thing to what you want, and I'm also obligated to tell you it's a bad idea. Such is C++.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it seems every time someone suggests a macro it comes with the disclaimer "don't do it" :).

Comment: @Vii It's because most good C++ programmersk now that it comes at high cost. That macro cannot be put in a namespace, you can't really build other abstractions on top of a macro because the preprocessor runs first, leads to surprising errors like arguments being evaluated twice, etc. For perspective I almost certainly would not allow the macro I wrote above to pass code review in any team I was involved in, but hey,  I'm just handing you the rope, you can decide whether you want to hang yourself or not ;-)